# JS Canvas elements not rendering as array

Tags: javascript, canvas

When i make one object. The system works. A circle bounces around the screen and you can click on it to return a function. However when i set createArray to 10 or any number higher than 1. The system breaks and it only produces the last one in the array. I labelled each so i see a ball saying '10' in the center if i set the array to generate 10. Now without the movement functions the thing generates as many cicles i want happily. so all parts work individually.
The issue is somehow i need to render all items from the array.
ive added some notes to explain bits.
Any ideas how to generate lots of circles im calling algae throughout?

```
class Algae {
  constructor(xpos, ypos, radius, color, count, speed) {
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.count = count;
    this.clicked = function() {
        console.log('CLIIIIIIICKED');
        clickedOnCount++;
        renderCounts();
    };
    this.speed = speed;

    this.dx = 1 * this.speed;
    this.dy = 1 * this.speed;
  }

  draw(context) {
    context.beginPath();

    context.strokeStyle = this.color;
    context.lineWidth = 4;

    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.textBaseline = 'middle';
    context.font = '20px Arial';
    context.fillText(this.count, this.xpos, this.ypos);

    context.arc(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);

    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }

  update() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    this.draw(context);

    if (this.xpos > canvas.width) {
        this.dx = -this.dx;
    }

    if ( (this.xpos - this.radius) < 0) {
        this.dx = -this.dx;
    }

    if (this.ypos > canvas.height) {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
    }

    if ( (this.ypos - this.radius) < 0) {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
    }

    this.xpos += this.dx;
    this.ypos += this.dy;
  }
}

let createArray = 1; // this is the number of circles to producde
let algaeCounter = 1; // number inside circle
let algaeArray = []; // array of all created
let clickedOnCount = 0 // number of time clicked on moving circle

// On click event swarm
function clickFunctionSwarm() {
  for (i = 0; i < createArray; i++) {
    let random_x = Math.random() * window_width;
    let random_y = Math.random() * window_height;

    const algaeSwarm = new Algae(random_x, random_y, 20, 'red', algaeCounter, 2);
    algaeSwarm.draw(context);
    algaeArray.push(algaeSwarm);

    algaeCounter++;
  }
}

// calls its self over and over to move around
function updateSwarm() {
    requestAnimationFrame(updateSwarm);
    algaeArray.forEach((algaeSwarm => {

        algaeSwarm.update()
    })) 
}

function renderCounts() {
    countContainer.innerText = `Algae Clicked On: ${clickedOnCount}`
}

function run() {
    renderCounts();
    updateSwarm()
}

run();
```

Adjusting numbers of items generated and foreaching

Comment: One issue I see is that you aren't declaring `i` anywhere, so your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). But it's not clear to me why that would cause what you're describing, since you don't seem to use `i` in a way where it being a global would be an acute problem, so it may be unrelated. (Still worth fixing. :-) )

Comment: Each instance will clear the whole canvas, and thus the drawings of the previous ones. Clear the context only once in your main rendering loop.

Comment: Wise advice with the i. done it. And Thank you the context clearing was the issue, i moved the line and it works great now